# Will MySQL use a covering index for LIKE?

Tags: mysql, sql, performance

Let's say I have a poor man's search engine and I'm searching a table of products...

```
select
  category_id
from products
where
  description like '%blue%'
```

I know what you must be thinking. If you remove the leading wildcard, the query can use an index on description properly. **That's not what I'm asking.**

If I have the following index, will the query perform any better?

```
IX_description (description, category_id)
```

I figured it could just scan the index instead of the whole table but that's not what EXPLAIN is telling me. If I remove the leading wildcard, the "extra" field in EXPLAIN tells me I'm covered, but if I put it back, it doesn't.

Shouldn't I be covered in both cases since I'm only accessing category_id and description, despite using description differently?

Edit:

I just realized this query, as written, doesn't really make a lot of semantic sense if products are many to one category_id. So there's a missing DISTINCT, which makes the correct index

```
 IX_description (category_id, description)
```

This actually does get covered. But I would still like to know why it isn't getting covered in the scenario as originally stated.

Comment: All of a sudden I am unable to recreate this scenario. Is the query engine just being finicky?

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using wildcards on both ends of the like query there is generally no point for MySQL to use the index. Doing a full table scan will be just as fast anyway.

However... an index-only scan should be possible here, so I am wondering if it's not using that because there are updates on the table. Or simply because it might be a worse query plan.

A little more info about index-only scans for anyone interested: http://mysqlha.blogspot.nl/2010/11/how-are-index-only-scans-implemented-in.html

Comment: Why would a table scan be just as fast? Isn't an index scan much faster due to its smaller size?

Comment: Size isn't really that relevant; You can 'skip' just as fast over the portions/bytes of the full table that you don't need to process.

Comment: @MarkCanlas: it's also about being able to read a large blob of data (sequentially) at the same time. If it can do a full sequential scan with the table and not with the index, than shouldn't. In this case however I guess that the query planner just doesn't understand but I am no MySQL expert. Can you try a `FORCE INDEX`?

Comment: I did try FORCE INDEX and it made the performance time worse initially, which is very surprising. Then after some fiddling the index finally "caught" and the query was fast. But why it didn't from the get go is the puzzling part.

Comment: The MySQL query planner can be very silly at times... in some cases you really have to force the indexes.